# Clob data don't want to save (Oracle, XML, Clob, PL/SQL, UTL_FILE)

Tags: xml, oracle11g, clob, xmltype, utl-file

I want to take data from table (xmltype) and save to the file on disc.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
     p_directory varchar2(10) := 'DMP_XML';
     p_fileName varchar2(10) := 'test.xml';
     file_handle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
     clob_part VARCHAR2(1024);
     clob_length NUMBER;
     offset NUMBER := 1;     
     clob_in clob;
     v_xml_data xmltype;

   begin
      file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_directory, p_fileName, 'W');
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, '<?xml version="1."?>');

       select
         extract(
           XMLELEMENT("TAG",
             XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT("Col1", Col1 ||''|| Col2) order by col1)),'/"') as xml_test
       into v_xml_data
       from table1;      

      clob_in := v_xml_data.GETclobVAL();
      clob_length := LENGTH(clob_in);

      LOOP
        EXIT WHEN offset >= clob_length;
        clob_part := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (clob_in, 1024, offset);
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(clob_part);
        UTL_FILE.PUT(file_handle, clob_part);
        offset := offset + 1024;
      END LOOP;


      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file_handle);
      UTL_FILE.fclose(file_handle);
   end;
```

I have tested that first line is added to my test.xml file.
Also, I see that clob_part has string values (when uncoment DBMS_OUTPUT).

But I got error as below:
[image]

and I'm not able to save file with data.

Comment: Try removing the FFLUSH call. I've never used it (only called CLOSE) and has always worked for me

Comment: it did not help

Comment: The error message should be added as text, not as image

Comment: Then you have to check if the file is not blocked by some other process (or by some old execution you made before and didn't closed properly the file). Have you tried sending to a different file?

Comment: yes, I changed the name couple of times and always have the same error, if I do like  UTL_FILE.PUT(file_handle, 'xxx'); is adding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below resolve the case:

```
    LOOP
     EXIT WHEN offset >= clob_length;
      clob_part := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (clob_in, 1022, offset);
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, clob_part);
      offset := offset + 1022;
    END LOOP;
```

**Other solution**:

```
create or replace procedure write_xml_clob_to_file_xml (p_directory varchar2, p_file_name varchar2) as

     v_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
     v_amount INTEGER := 32767;
     v_xml_data XMLType;
     v_char_buffer varchar2(32767);

     l_lob clob;
     l_idx pls_integer;
     start_pos pls_integer := 1;

begin
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_lob,true);
   v_file:= UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_directory,p_file_name,'w',v_amount);

   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, '<?xml version="1."?>');

  select
         extract(
           XMLELEMENT("TAG",
             XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT("MYTAG", Col1 ||''|| Col2) order by col1)),'/TAG') as xml_test
       into v_xml_data
       from table1;  

  l_lob :=v_xml_data.GETclobVAL();

  loop l_idx := instr(l_lob,'</MYTAG>');
         if l_idx > 0 then
             UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file,substr(l_lob,start_pos,l_idx+12));           
           l_lob := substr(l_lob,l_idx+13);
         else
            UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file,substr(l_lob,start_pos));
           exit;
         end if;
      end loop; 

  UTL_FILE.fflush(v_file);
  UTL_FILE.fclose(v_file);
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_lob);

end write_xml_clob_to_file_xml;
```